# HttpContext.Current.User.Principal vs WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

What's the difference in an asp.NET environment with Windows Authentication and Identity Impersonation turned on, between HttpContext.Current.User.Principal and WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()?

Comment: Although this question has already been answered, I found out that [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1507047.aspx?WindowsIdentity%20GetCurrent%20Name%20vs%20User%20Identity%20Name) and [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302377.aspx) answered it more clearly.

Answer (score 16):

According to this forum on [`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` vs. `User.Identity.Name`](http://forums.asp.net/t/1507047.aspx):

> - `User.Identity.Name` represents the identity passed from IIS.
> - `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` is the identity under which the thread is running.

Depending on your app's authentication settings in IIS, they will return different values:

```
| Anonymous | Impersonate | User.Identity.Name | WindowsIndentiy.GetCurrent()  |
|-----------|-------------|--------------------|-------------------------------|
| Yes       | True        | Empty String       | IUSR_<machineName>            |
| Yes       | False       | Empty String       | NT Authority\Network Service  |
| No        | True        | domain\user        | domain\user                   |
| No        | False       | domain\user        | NT Authority\Network Service  |
```

**Legend**:

- Where **domain\user** will show up as:

  - domain\user for Active Directory
  - machineName\userName for local account
- Where **NT Authority\Network Service** will show up as:

  - NT Authority\Network Service for Windows Server or ASP.NET
  - machineName\ASPNET_WP for Windows XP