# IIS not picking up Windows User

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms

I made a web application which displays Windows User Name on top right.
If I open the webapp on `localhost:5903/index.aspx` I get correct Windows User.
Like this -
[image]

But if I open `localhost/db/index.aspx` I get IIS AppPool User - 

[image]

Here db is the directory which has my app.

I have no idea why is this happening. I want the localhost to show the correct Username as well.

My IIS tree, here DB(1) is my webapp -

[image]

My C# code which picks Windows Identity -

```
<li><% string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;%>
<a><%= userName %></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup the site in IIS for Windows Authentication only and turn off Anonymous.

Go into IIS for you site then under Features View.

Then under the IIS category > Authentication > Set Windows Authentication to Enabled and all others (Anonymous....others) to Disabled.

Instead of...

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Use

```
 HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: Windows Authentication was already enabled. I disabled Anonymous. No change. Still getting IIS AppPool

Comment: Updated the answer above.. use HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

Comment: It worked ! Can you tell me what's the difference and why wasn't it working with localhost ?

Comment: PirateX. LocalHost (with the Studio Server is not running under windows auth) This post answers it well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402249/httpcontext-current-user-principal-vs-windowsidentity-getcurrent